# page building using a toolbar to select components (drag'n drop, IPE) on creation and edition

Tags: layout-builder

Of all the drupal solutions for page building, i do not see any that uses the same UI for creation and edition.
Layout builder allows to place and (re)organise entities in layout sections but only once the entity has been created.

I would ideally imagine a toolbar that allows to pick from all the components available ( paragraphs , custom blocks or other type of components) and place them in sections/region while creating a new page.
Editind the content would be looking just exactly the same in term of UI (in place editing and toolar available to select the components to add and configure.

Any hints on existing solutions or approaches to implement that ?

Comment: Probably because the storage has to attach to an entity first before you can do so, which isn't available until its been saved the first time. I'd be surprised if there wasn't a contrib module working on this.

Comment: if u happen to find that contrib module, i'd be happy to hear it

Answer (score 0):

the module geysir might do the job.

[geysir](https://www.drupal.org/project/geysir)